# Can I intersect (slice) a multipatch geometry and obtain the perimeter line of the intersection as a result?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, 3d, arcscene

Can I intersect (slice) a multipatch geometry with a vertical polygon (or an extruded line) to obtain the perimeter line of the intersection? (or better yet a polygon)

I am creating fairly complex vertical cross sections in ArcGIS and my workflow for creating a sectional view of complex subsurface geological features is VERY time consuming.

I am thinking the "Intersect 3D Line With Multipatch" tool might somehow be utilized but it only seems to work with 3D lines and points whereas I need to extract a slice from the multipatch.

[image]

Comment: have you figured out how to slice a multipatch feature? I too would like to perform the same task, but feel quite limited in using ArcScene for this exercise. Thank you

Comment: Yes if the section is east to west or north to south. But it's very labor intensive. I do this in Leapfrog Mining or Geosoft.